# Friedman's approach of proving Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

Tags: vector-spaces, inner-products, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

In a linear vector space that is the Euclidean space $\mathbb{E}_{\infty}$, we have the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

$$ |\langle x,y \rangle| \leq |x| |y|,$$

where both $x,y \in\mathbb{E}_{\infty}$. Explicitly $x=(\xi_{1},\xi_{2},\cdots)$ and $y=(\eta_{1},\eta_{2},\cdots)$, and we assume here that both are finite in length (i.e. the series for $|x|^{2}$ and $|y|^{2}$ converge).

I am familiar with several proofs of this inequality. However, I am unable to follow the particular approach that Friedman indicates in one of the problems (Problem 1.2, p.6) in his [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486664449) (also I noticed it's posted online [here](http://www.astrosen.unam.mx/%7Eaceves/Metodos/ebooks/friedman.pdf)) where he says that we can prove the inequality by using the result

$$ |\alpha x + \beta y|^{2}=\langle \alpha x + \beta y, \alpha x + \beta y\rangle = \alpha^{2} \langle x,x \rangle +2 \alpha \beta \langle x,y \rangle + \beta^{2} \langle y,y \rangle,$$

which holds for any $\alpha,\beta$ scalars, and by putting

$$ x_{n}=(\xi_{1},\xi_{2},\cdots,\xi_{n},0,0,\cdots), $$
$$ \alpha = |y|^{2}, $$
$$ \beta=\langle x_{n},y\rangle, $$

to prove that $\langle x_{n},y\rangle \leq |x_{n}| |y|$.

How do we proceed using this specific approach (not other approaches) to explicitly reach the inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect it's a typo, and $\ \beta\ $ should be $\ -\big\langle x_n, y\big\rangle\ $. You'll then get (with $\ \alpha=|y|^2\ $)
\begin{align}
\big|\alpha x_n+\beta y|^2&=|y|^4|x_n|^2-2|y|^2\big\langle x_n, y\big\rangle^2+ |y|^2\big\langle x_n, y\big\rangle^2\\
&=|y|^4|x_n|^2-|y|^2\big\langle x_n, y\big\rangle^2\ ,
\end{align}
or
\begin{align}
\big\langle x_n, y\big\rangle^2&= |y|^2|x_n|^2-\frac{\big|\alpha x_n+\beta y|^2}{|y|^2}\\
&\le |y|^2|x_n|^2\ ,
\end{align}
from which the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality follows immediately.

Comment: Ah, that explains it, I think! Thanks!  But why did he bother using $x_{n}$ at all here (instead of $x$)? Couldn't we just do the same with $x$ (since it is assumed to have finite length, so the series for $|x|^{2}$ converges)?

Comment: I presume it's because if you use $\ x\ $ instead, you have to show that the series for $\ \langle x,y\rangle\ $ converges to justify your expansion of $\ |\alpha x+\beta y|^2\ $. While this isn't hard, it still has to be done for the proof to be watertight.  This also applies to Friedman's proof, however, and the convergence doesn't follow immediately from his final inequality, so I guess my assertion that the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality follows "immediately" from it  is a mild exaggeration.

Comment: But would you agree that if all series are assumed to converge, then it wouldn't make a difference using $x$ or $x_{n}$?

Comment: Yes, *if* you make that assumption.  While Friedman's exposition might be a little confusing, his purpose seems to be to get you to prove that $\ \mathbb{E}_\infty\ $ is a linear space via the exercises $\mathbf{1.1}$ to $\mathbf{1.3}$. He apparently expects that you won't prove that all the necessary series converge until you get to exercise $\mathbf{1.3}$.

Comment: It begs the question why didn't he treat $y$ similarly (i.e. why not used $y_{n}$)? Sure, when one multiplies with $x_{n}$ it will be similarly truncated, but in other terms $y$ is on its own, yet he only took $x_{n}$ not $y_{n}$. I wonder whether he is alluding to something else.

Comment: You know that the sequence for $\ |y|^2\ $ converges because $\ y\in\mathbb{E}_\infty\ $, that for $\ |\alpha x_n + \beta y|^2\ $ converges because its tail is just that of $\ \beta y\ $, and $\ \langle x_n,y\rangle\ $ is only a finite sum, so it's possible to get away with truncating just one of $\ x\ $ and $\ y\ $ (though you could, of course, do it by truncating both).

Comment: Agreed. But if $|x|^{2}$ and $|y|^{2}$ converge (because they belong to $\mathbb{E}_{\infty}$), then we have at some term ($n$) in their series that $|x_{n+1}/x_{n}|<1$ and $|y_{n+1}/y_{n}|<1$, so the series for $\langle x,y \rangle$ will have at some point also $|x_{n+1} y_{n+1}|/|x_{n} y_{n}|<1$ as a result, and thus it will converge. Thus, since $|x|, |y|, \langle x,y \rangle$ all are finite, then so must be $|\alpha x + \beta y|$ as their combination, proving closure in $\mathbb{E}_{\infty}$. So, why bother with introducing a truncated $x$ (namely $x_{n}$)?

Comment: You need more than just a decreasing tail to give you convergence (consider the harmonic series), and the convergence of $\ |x|^2\ $ and $\ |y|^2\ $ doesn't give you a decreasing tail anyway.  I agree , however, with your wider point that Friedman could have proved convergence more transparently than the rigmarole he actually goes through

Comment: But if a series has an absolute convergence, then it will converge. Taking the D'Alembert (ratio) convergence test here will show that $(x_{n+1}/x_{n})^{2}<1$ at some point $n$ in the series, since $x$ is assumed convergent by belonging to $\mathbb{E}_{\infty}$, and therefore $|x_{n+1}/x_{n}|<1$ (and similar for $y$). So why isn't it a simple case of absolute convergence here? Am I missing something?

Comment: The ratio test requires the existence of a constant  $\ c<1\ $, and an integer  $\ N>1\ $ such that  $\ \left|\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\right|<c\ $ for all  $\ n\ge N\ $. But even if  $\ \left|\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\right|<1\ $ for all $\ n\ $, that is not sufficient to guarantee the convergence of the series  $\ \sum_nx_n\ $. As I've already alluded to, the harmonic series  $\ \sum_n\frac{1}{n}\ $ diverges, even though $\ \left|\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\right|<1\ $ for all $\ n\ $  when  $\ x_n=\frac{1}{n}\ $.
 
.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the harmonic series has $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} |\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_{n}}|=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} |\frac{n}{n+1}|=1$ (not $<1$), which is not conclusive in the ratio test, and further inspection using other methods like the Comparison test reveal its divergence. Here, however, if $x \in \mathbb{E}_{\infty}$, then by definition this means that $\lim |x_{n+1}/x_{n}|^{2}<1$ and therefore $\lim |x_{n+1}/x_{n}|<1$ (similarly for $y$). Thus $|x_{n+1} y_{n+1}|/|x_{n} y_{n}|<1$, which shows convergence of $\langle x,y \rangle$. If not, then how would you prove its convergence?

Comment: No.  You *cannot* conclude that $\ \lim\left|\frac{ x_{n+1}}{ x_n}\right|^2<1\ $ from the fact that $\ x\in\mathbb{E}_\infty\ $.  The ratio test doesn't allow you to conclude *anything* about the limit $\ \lim \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|\ $ from the absolute convergence of $\ \sum_n a_n\ $. If
$$
a_n=\cases{\frac{1}{n^2}&for $\ n\ $ odd\\
            \frac{1}{n^3}&for $\ n\ $ even ,}
$$
for instance, then $\ \sum_n a_n\ $ is absolutely convergent, but $\ \limsup\left|\frac{ a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=$$\infty\ $, because $\ \left|\frac{ a_{2n+1}}{a_{2n}}\right|=\frac{2n^3}{(2n+1)^2}\ $.

Comment: I'm not aware of any simpler way of proving the convergence of $\ \sum_n \left|x_ny_n\right|\ $ than using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for truncated sequences to conclude that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N \left|x_ny_n\right|\le\sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^N \left|x_n\right| \sum_{n=1}^N \left|y_n\right|^2}\le\|x\|\,\|y\|
$$
and therefore $\ \sum_n \left|x_ny_n\right|\ $ converges by the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116116/discussion-between-lonza-leggiera-and-user135626).