# Proving that an infinite Euclidean space is linear vector space

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, vector-spaces, inner-products

Assuming real quantities, with the scalar product defined as

$$\langle x,y \rangle = x_{1}y_{1}+x_{2}y_{2}+\cdots, $$

where $x,y$ are vectors in the real infinite Euclidean space $\mathbb{E}_{\infty}$, and assuming that all vectors in such space are by definition of finite length (e.g. $|x|=\langle x,x \rangle=x^{2}_{1}+x^{2}_{2}+\cdots$ converges to a finite value), how can we prove that the product  $\langle x,y \rangle$ will also exist and be finite?  (In other words, we prove that $\mathbb{E}_{\infty}$ will be a linear vector space.)

I am especially interested if there are two approaches of proof: (1) one that is simple and does not use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality (if possible), and (2) another one that uses the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. This will help me understand the differences and compare with literature (e.g. Friedman's [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486664449), ch-1).

Finally, my attempt for the former was to use the D'Alambert (ratio) test to say that, if $|x|,|y|$ converge, then we know that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_{n}}|^{2}<1$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |\frac{y_{n+1}}{y_{n}}|^{2}<1$, thus $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_{n}}|<1$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |\frac{y_{n+1}}{y_{n}}|<1$.  Then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_{n}}\frac{y_{n+1}}{y_{n}}|<1$ gives the absolute convergence of the series for $\langle x,y \rangle$. But I am told this is not a rigorous answer because the convergence of a given series does not tell us anything about the ratio test.  Does this also mean that the ratio test for absolute convergence is sufficient but not necessary?  Any elaboration on this would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't rule out $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_{n}}|=1$ even for an absolute convergent series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ratio test only says that if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\right| < 1$ then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges absolutely; the converse is false - for instance, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges despite the fact that the ratio of consecutive terms tends to $1$. Thus, it's not much good here - all you are given is that some sequences converge, but nothing about how quickly they do so.

A better thing to note is that, if you have some sequence of $a_n$, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges absolutely if and only if there is some upper bound $B$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^N |a_n| \leq B$ for all $N$ - this is, more or less, the [monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Convergence_of_a_monotone_sequence_of_real_numbers) for real numbers. This is a more helpful characterization because it is bidirectional - you can use it to transform your givens into some statement about finite sums and then to transform a statement about finite sums back into a statement about limits.

More clearly, your goal could be:

> Suppose that there are $B_1$ and $B_2$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^Nx_n^2\leq B_1$ and $\sum_{n=1}^Ny_n^2\leq B_2$ for all $N$. Show that there is some $B$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^N|x_ny_n| \leq B$ for all $N$.

The motivation for transforming the goal thusly is that we have gotten rid of most the analytical difficulties and turned this into an algebra problem.

The most straightforward thing to do would be to say:

> Let $B=B_1+B_2$. Note that for any $n$, we have either that $|x_n|\leq |y_n|$ or $|y_n|\leq |x_n|$. In the former case, note $|x_ny_n| \leq y_n^2$ and in the latter $|x_ny_n| \leq x_n^2$. In any case, $|x_ny_n| \leq x_n^2+y_n^2$. Therefore, $\sum_{n=1}^N|x_ny_n| \leq \sum_{n=1}^Nx_n^2 + \sum_{n=1}^N y_n^2 \leq B_1+B_2$ as desired, so $\sum_{n=1}^Nx_ny_n$ converges absolutely.

If you wanted to use Cauchy-Schwarz, you could use it here too:

> Let $B=\sqrt{B_1B_2}$. For any $n$, consider the vectors $(|x_1|,\ldots,|x_n|)$ and $(|y_1|,\ldots,|y_n|)$. By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality applied to these vectors, we have
> $$\sum_{n=1}^N |x_ny_n| \leq \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^N x_n^2 \cdot \sum_{n=1}^N y_n^2} \leq \sqrt{B_1B_2}.$$

This gives the algebraic result you need just as well - and gives a somewhat tighter bound on the ultimate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_ny_n|$, although this is a bit redundant since you could prove the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality as soon as you know that this space is in fact an inner product space. Note that the proofs are essentially the same - after transforming the analytical statement into an algebraic one, we just need some algebra to fill in a gap and can do this in a number of ways.

Comment: [1/2] Many thanks! I like the clarity of your answer.  I have a few questions: (1) am I correct in observing that these two proofs that you gave will immediately also apply if we had the complex version of this problem (with complex inner product, say $\langle x,y \rangle=\sum x^{*}_{i}y_{i} $)?  (2) could you please explain a bit what did you mean by tighter bound in the second proof? (3) You said that proving CS inequality or proving its inner product space will follow from one another: am I correct in explaining this by saying that the linear combination will be

Comment: [2/2] given by $|\alpha x + \beta y|^{2} = \alpha^{2} |x|^{2} +2 \alpha \beta \langle x,y \rangle + \beta^{2} |y|^{2}$, and if either $\langle x,y \rangle$ or $|\alpha x + \beta y|$ are finite, the other will be finite as a result?
(4) Finally, I would be grateful if you could please help explain to me the method in which Friedman gave a proof using a series that is truncated as $x=(x_{1}, x_{2}, \cdots, x_{n}, 0,0, \cdots)$, which I asked here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3900064/friedmans-approach-of-proving-cauchy-schwarz-inequality And whether this is related to your approach?

Comment: Friedman did not comment on the rationale behind working with such truncated series to prove the convergence, and how they are related to the nontruncated case. So any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: (1) Yes. (2) The first proof implies only $\langle x,y\rangle \leq \langle x,x\rangle + \langle y,y\rangle$ whereas the second implies the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality immediately. (3) I mean that once you know $\langle x,y\rangle$ is finite (and linear in both terms), you can prove Cauchy-Schwarz via whatever the usual proof you use for it is - and considering $|\alpha x + \beta y|^2 \geq 0$ is one way to do that. This is not a helpful way to get at finiteness though, because proving that $|x+y|^2$ exists if $|x|^2$ and $|y|^2$ do is no easier than showing $\langle x,y\rangle$ exists.

Comment: @user135626 (4) The proof you link to seems to be a proof of Cauchy-Schwarz - it looks inadequate to prove convergence of $\langle x,y\rangle$ (as it only gives an upper bound to partial sums of $\sum x_ny_n$ where both positive and negative terms appear). However, it's totally unnecessary to use truncations for that purpose - I honestly have no explanation for why he would do that. Yes, the limit of the truncated inner products $\langle x_n,y\rangle$ is $\langle x,y\rangle$ and if you combine this with the fact that $|x_n||y| \leq |x||y|$ you get a proof, but it's not a *good* proof.

Comment: I have been agonizing about why Friedman used such truncated version of $x$ in Problem 1.2 on p.6 to train the reader (http://www.astrosen.unam.mx/%7Eaceves/Metodos/ebooks/friedman.pdf). And actually in the following question 1.3 he says that this step of proving CS inequality with truncated $x_{n}$ will lead to proving that $\mathbb{E}_{\infty}$ is linear vector space.  Am I missing something here?  Friedman's book is quite famous and I feel hesitant to brush his method aside. Any suggestions?  And do you have any recommended text on this subject that you prefer?

Comment: @user135626 With the same fiddling I do in my answer, one can plug in the $\langle x_n,y\rangle \leq |x_n|\cdot |y| \leq |x|\cdot |y|$ to fill in the algebraic part of the proof - it's not wrong, just an odd way to go about it. The only reason I can think that Friedman might proceed this way would be to avoid formally defining inner products abstractly prior to this proof, but to still get the reader to prove stuff about them at that point. I wouldn't fret too much - it's just a hint on an exercise. These kinds of oddities seem to exist in every book on mathematics.